# AFHTTPSessionManager calling localhost ip

Tags: ios, node.js, afnetworking-2

I'm trying to run my iOS app, having it pull data from the node.js server I have running locally.

The problem I'm having is that when I use AFHTTPSessionManager's GET method, it keeps on timing out.

I've tried doing the request from my browser and my locally running node server is returning the json as expected. I've also tried curling from the cl and it also returns as expected.

Is there something I'm missing?

Here's my test code:

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
[manager GET:@"http://192.168.33.327/api/v1/item" parameters:nil      success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
      } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
   NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
      }];
```

I've also tried initializing the manager with a base url, then just passing in the path to GET but it still times out. (the error I get in error says the error code is -1001)

Also you'll notice there is no port number on the code I've pasted. at first I had it on port 8080, but thought that might be causing a problem, so I ran node on port 80 instead, but it still didn't help.

Thanks!

Comment: Here is the deal, if you are having network issues run a network analyzer and find out what is happening, Charles Proxy is the OSX go-to analyzer, free 30 day trial. Run Charles Proxy on both and find the difference. For curl and Charles add `--proxy localhost:8888` to the curl command. The bad news is you really should learn something about http requests. Also keep in mind that curl will run commands that are not kosher like sending data on a GET.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I re-ran my code this morning and it worked. I have no idea what the problem was, I must have had another service running yesterday that was interfering.